# parameters of a linear code constructed from another

Tags: coding-theory

For $C$, a $[n,k,d]$ linear code, we'll construct the following new code:
$$
\widetilde{C}=\{(c_1,c_2,...,c_{i-1},c_{i+1},..,c_n)|c=(c_1,c_2,...,c_{i-1},0,c_{i+1},..,c_n) \in C\}
$$
Now, $\widetilde{C}$ is a $[\widetilde{n},\widetilde{k},\widetilde{d}]$ linear code.
How can I show that the new code has either $\widetilde{k}=k$ or $\widetilde{k}=k-1$?

I've tried showing it through $C'=\{(c_1,c_2,...,c_{i-1},0,c_{i+1},..,c_n) \in C\}$ 
but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely, the dimension of $C'$ is less or equal than $k$, since $C'\subseteq C$. You have to show that it doesn't get smaller than $k-1$.

Write a basis of $C$, call the basis vector $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k\}$, and suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_r$ have a 0 in the $i$-th position, so $v_1,\dots,v_r\in C'$, and $v_{r+1},\dots,v_k$ have a non-zero number on the $i$-th position.

Since the code is linear, we can scale these vectors into $w_{r+1},\dots,w_k \in C$ so that all them have 1 on the $i$-th position. This means that $w_{r+1}-w_k ,\dots,w_{k-1}-w_k$ are still linearly independent and they have all 0 on the $i$-th position.

From this,
$$
v_1,\dots,v_r,w_{r+1}-w_k ,\dots,w_{k-1}-w_k\in C'
$$
and they're all lin.ind., so the dimension of $C'$  is $k$ or $k-1$